# Get user details from user name(Sqlite, PHP)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite on my website. I just want to get birth date of a user from database.

Here is the script I tried but didn't work.

```
$data = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * FROM userdatabse WHERE title='.$username);

echo $data->date;
```

Comment: can u translate into english? `rawQuery diee kono username er detail ber korar way ase?`

Comment: u need to use quotes for username like `$db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM userdatabse WHERE title='".$username."'");`

Comment: you also need to check what are u getting in `print_r($data);`

Comment: than u need to chk it `print_r($data);`

Comment: Blank.......... :(

Comment: it means, your query not returning anything. run your query in phpmyadmin is it working? or share more code like connection etc.

Comment: It works on phpmyadmin. I tried this: SELECT * FROM userdatabse WHERE title="Username"

Comment: maybe your database not connected or maybe you are not getting anytthing in `$username` first of all chk is `echo $username;` its defined or not?

Comment: I just need to add this: echo $data[0]['date'];

Comment: it means `print_r($data);` is returing the array and now u have resolved the issue good work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, **querySingle()** executes a query and returns a single result.

Try

```
$result = $db->querySingle('SELECT date_of_birth FROM userdatabse WHERE title='.$username', true);

var_dump($result);
echo $result;
```

**NOTE :**

Since we queried for just one column(date of birth), therefore it will return a string with the date of birth.

Had we queried for many columns say date_of_birth and mobile_number, it would have returned an array with these fields.

Example :

```
$result = $db->querySingle('SELECT date_of_birth, mobile_number FROM userdatabse WHERE title='.$username', true);

print_r($result);
```

The above query will return something like :

```
Array
(
    [date_of_birth] => 1993-05-05
    [mobile_number] => 9999999999
)
```

where as the query :

```
$result = $db->querySingle('SELECT date_of_birth FROM userdatabse WHERE title='.$username', true);

echo $result;
```

will return something like this :

```
1993-05-05
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.